# google search console data does not match results in Search Analytics: query tester on the Google API Reference

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I've been testing out my data on this page:
https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/searchanalytics/query

The data I am receive seems to be off compared to the data I am showing in google search console. I am wondering if this may be the result of a sampling error or something incorrect with my query. Any input on what may cause the data to change from Google Search Console to the Query result?

```
{
  "startDate": "2019-04-01",
  "endDate": "2019-04-30",
  "dimensions": [
    "query"
  ],
  "searchType": "web",
  "dimensionFilterGroups": [
    {
      "groupType": "and",
      "filters": [
        {
          "dimension": "page",
          "operator": "contains",
          "expression": "/about/who-we-are/community/"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Data from query does not match Google search Console.

Example:

```
Google Search Console
"community"
Clicks 8
Impressions 13

Query
"community"
   ],
   "clicks": 17.0,
   "impressions": 26.0,
```

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed some discrepancies between search console UI and API. I have similar problems and i found these documentation from Google:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7042828
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7576553?hl=en&visit_id=637099209145003362-895149723&rd=1
Google has a certain aggregation method in which if you query from API in combination with page grouping the result will be different.
From UI:
If one query returned your property at positions 2, 4, and 6, its position is counted as 2 (the topmost position).
If a second query returned your property at positions 3, 5, and 9, its position is counted as 3 (the topmost position).
The average position across these two queries is (2 + 3)/2 = 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation is a big difference. Google does this weird in the interface. It's not really an aggregation and then an average. They check how often you rank in specific types and then basically uses MIN(position) to fetch the best position of every result type you rank in. What we tend to do in BQ/API/Looker is using the AVG(position) of all appearances, instead of only the MIN of each type.

This is explained here:
[https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7042828#position:~:text=have%20position%206.-,Average%20position,-The%20position%20value](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7042828#position:%7E:text=have%20position%206.-,Average%20position,-The%20position%20value)

[image]

Additionally and probably the largest impact is that Google reports it as differences from privacy sensitive data point of view. John Mueller (see linked video) specifically mentions all data coming from the same tables. This is both explained here:

- https://youtu.be/a5J73nYDU8E?t=2051
- https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2022/10/performance-data-deep-dive#privacy-filtering